# Using indexOf() to search array inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, indexof

I'm try to search an array of id's `[1, 2, 3]` with `indexOf()` inside an `ng-repeat` loop, but probably because of a wrong data type, it doesn't work.

```
<li ng-repeat="member in message.members">
    Member ID: {{ member.id }}
    <span ng-if="message.read_by.indexOf(member.id) > -1">Read</span>
</li>
```

The array `message.read_by = [1, 2, 3]` and `member.id = 1` printed correct for each member inside the loop, but the `message.read_by.indexOf(member.id) > -1` always returns false.

If i replace the `member.id` with `message.read_by.indexOf(1) > -1` returns true.

I tried to pass the member.id on `parseInt()` or `toString()` because it looks to me as a problem because a wrong data type but that doesn't work also.

What's the correct method i should use to pass the `member.id` value?

Comment: Show `message.members` object

Comment: use function checkpresent(memeberid, message){if()return true else false}

Comment: Can you create `jsfiddle` demo of this

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/21h8r71p/ - looks fine

Comment: @Tushar the `message.members` it's an object `{ id="1", username="uname"}`

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks for this, probably the data types are different in my case. I have the read_by array `[1, 2, 3]` and a member `{id="1", username="uname"}` but doesn't work as on your example. I'm getting those data from a JSON response.

Comment: @Philip it is because your id property is a string

Comment: @ArunPJohny, I tried to parseInt() the id but it doesn't work. Is there a way to do this on the view?

Comment: @Philip http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/21h8r71p/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is the data type of the values, the `read_by` array has int values where as `member.id` is string.

One easy fix is

```js
var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function() {})

app.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
  $scope.isRead = function(member) {
    return $scope.message.read_by.indexOf(+member.id) > -1;
  }
  $scope.message = {
    read_by: [1, 2, 3],
    members: [{
      id: "1"
    }, {
      id: "3"
    }, {
      id: "5"
    }]
  };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="AppController">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="member in message.members">
      Member ID: {{ member.id }}
      <span ng-if="isRead(member)">Read</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That's the best way to do this

Answer (score 1):

You can use `track by $index` for this purpose:

```
<li ng-repeat="member in message.members track by $index">
    Member ID: {{ member.id }}
    <span ng-if="$index > 1">Read</span>
</li>
```

Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) for more information.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question `I'm try to search an array of id's `